# How can i copy one file from one directory to another directory in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, telnet, beanshell

I am trying to copy one file from one directory to another directory using Telnet Server. Can we do this in Jmeter. I am using Beanshell Sampler for that. Please anyone guide me on this.

Thanks in advance,
Anto

Answer (score 1):

Anto, no you can't do that with Beanshell sampler. I do not know about telnet but you can do this with SSH.

You do however have the SSHSampler:

- http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-ssh-sampler/wiki/SshSamplerTutorial
- http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-ssh-sampler/

So after you've filled in connection details, there is `execute` tab at the bottom with command so you can write inside `cp /path/to/dir1/file /path/to/dir2`

Comment: Thanks Ant. Please tell me the usage of Beanshell Sampler. If we use java code, what are the modifications we should do in the Beanshell Sampler?

Comment: @Anto you need not to modify anything, paste the java code and I'll take a look at it